# Is there a way I can tell a process before it starts up or after it starts up which IP address to use on Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, automated-tests, ip-address

I can program in C# so if there are any .NET classes available to reassigning IP addresses or if there is a command line operation for changing the IP address of a given process, that is what I think I'm looking for.

I'm doing some automated browser testing and I want to have requests coming to my site from different IP addresses. My web server has 15 IP addresses assigned to it so I want to have the browser make requests from a different IP address on each request. Or I want to be able to open multiple instance of a browser and have each instance use a different IP.

Answer (score 1):

I read about this today: [Why cloud-based load testing is a killer app](http://johngannonblog.com/2009/03/04/why-cloud-based-load-testing-is-a-killer-app/#)

You can use a cloud service (like Amazon's) to do load-testing by bringing up a large group of servers for a short period of time to test out your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [BindIPEndPointDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.bindipendpointdelegate.aspx) property of the ServicePoint class to specify the local IP address to use for a connection.

Comment: Now, what exactly was wrong with this answer? If you don't tell me, I can hardly be expected to do better next time!

Comment: Looks like essentially the right answer to me (I'll vote it back up). You set the IP address of your socket by changing its binding, that's basic IP socket stuff. OP needs to research sockets.